# Regular Expression to find multiple instances of %%{ANYTHING}%%

Tags: regex

```
SomeRandomText=%EXAMPLE1%,MoreRandomText=%%ONE%%!!%%TWO%%,YetMoreRandomText=%%THREE%%%FOUR%!!%FIVE%\%%SIX%%
```

I'm in need of a regular expression which can pull out anything which is wrapped in '%%'- so this regular expression would match only the following:

- %%ONE%%
- %%TWO%%
- %%THREE%%
- %%SIX%%

I've tried lots of different methods, and am sure there is a way to achieve this- but i'm struggeling as of yet. I mainly end up getting it where it will match everything from the first %% to the last %% in the string- which is not what i want. i think i need something like forward lookups, but struggling to implement

Comment: It would help if you showed what you tried even if it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: apologies- i wanted to do this, but i'm not in the office today. thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) match, using the  `?` modifier:

```
%%.*?%%
```

See it working online: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/oIjSAWOflD)

Comment: @TomBeech as per your OP this doesn't meet your requirements.  `I mainly end up getting it where it will match everything from the first %% to the last %% in the string- which is not what i want.`

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done be restricting what is allowed between the `%`s.

```
%%[^%]*%%
```

This is more widely supported than non-greedy matching, however
 note that this won't match %%A%B%%. Although, if necessary, this can be done with some modifications:

```
%%([^%]|%[^%])*%%
```

Or equivalently

```
%%(%?[^%])*%%
```